# How to set/update value in a xml file using requests in python

Tags: python, xml, python-requests

My xml file is located in local network : https://192.168.43.109/DevMgmt/NetAppsDyn.xml

Below is a part content of above xml I want to update :

```
    <nadyn:ProxyConfig>
    <dd:ResourceURI/>
    <dd:Port/>
    <dd:ProxySupport>off</dd:ProxySupport>
    </nadyn:ProxyConfig>
```

I want to set the 'ResourceUI' and 'Port' field in above xml:
I have used below code :

```
     import requests
     data = {
              'ProxySupport':'on'
              'ResourceURI':'web-proxy.xxx.yy.com',
              'Port':8080
            }

    URL = 'https://192.168.75.165/DevMgmt/NetAppsDyn.xml'

    # content Type
    head = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
    # sending get request
    gr= requests.get(url=URL)
    print gr

    # sending put request
    r = requests.put(url=URL, data=data,headers=head)
    print r.status_code
    # extracting response text
    output_xml = r.text
    print("The op xml is:%s" % output_xml)
```

Issue : The fields are not getting updated in xml using put request. I am able to see the response for get (request) , but for put request it is throwing errror code : 301 , resource has been moved permanently.

Comment: `PUT` request will not automagically update your XML file, your web server (and / or the code executed by this server) has to know how to handle that. What is your server?

Comment: @Arount, It is the Printer ip. I am connecting the Printer to a wireless network and then using the printer ip I am able to access the xml from my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the data format to be sent with xml tag in input as below and Now I am able to update the values.

```
data= ''' 
<nadyn:NetAppsDyn > 
  <nadyn:ProxyConfig> 
   <dd:ResourceURI>web-proxy.xx.com</dd:ResourceURI> 
   <dd:Port>8080</dd:Port> 
   <dd:UserName></dd:UserName> 
   <dd:ProxySupport>on</dd:ProxySupport> 
  </nadyn:ProxyConfig> 
</nadyn:NetAppsDyn>'''
```